# Discord.py embeds doesnt work/dont send in ctx

Tags: discord, discord.py

I made a `p!poll` command, but there's something wrong with it. Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

```py
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx, *, question):
    embed=discord.Embed(title='New Poll', color=0xe74c3c())
    embed.add_field(name=question, value=f'Asked by {ctx.author.mention}')
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await message.add_reaction('<:upvote:728305908093944011>')
    await message.add_reaction('<:downvote:728305851151941644>')
```

Also, for those who are patient enough to see the error code:

```
Ignoring exception in command poll:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 65, in poll
    embed=discord.Embed(title='New Poll', color=0xe74c3c())
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code or do you have any error?

Comment: yes, actually im gonna edit my question and put it in thx

Comment: `color=0xe74c3c()` includes an attempt to call a number as if it were a function.

Comment: oh what im dumb ;-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `()` the color hex

```py
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx, *, question):
    embed=discord.Embed(title='New Poll', color=0xe74c3c)
    embed.add_field(name=question, value=f'Asked by {ctx.author.mention}')
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await message.add_reaction('<:upvote:728305908093944011>')
    await message.add_reaction('<:downvote:728305851151941644>')
```